# SVN Repo Migration shows huge difference

Tags: svn, svn-server

We have recently migrated SVN Repository from Server A to Server B using the below steps.

- Using svnrdump we have taken the backup.

> ```
> svnrdump dump http://example.com/svn/repo1 > repo1.dump
> ```

- And restored it using svnadmin load command like the following,

> ```
>    svnadmin load /var/svn/repos/repo1 < repo1.dump
> ```

**Problem:**

1. The backup was successful showing around 42000 revisions.
2. When restored the dump, the restoration was successful showing only 38299 revisions. There is a difference of 3701 revisions.

How do we troubleshoot this issue further?

Comment: Did you check the command output whenever there were warnings or errors? That would be the first step.

Comment: Did you refer to the output of the backup? or the restoration?

Comment: Both would be important, the restoration probably more so.

Comment: The output of was quite large and I missed the initial part. Is there a way to redirect all the logs to a file? I tried something like the following but the file doesn't contain any details                                                                                                                         svnadmin load /var/svn/repos/repo1 < repo1.dump 2>&1 | tee /tmp/back_logs.txt

Comment: That should actually work, if it doesn't increase the console buffer size to fit (more) of the output.